# this puzzle is based

Tags: mathematics, cipher, number-property

This message is a basic numeric substitution cipher. The key is the standard, regular alphabet in the correct order (ABC...XYZ).

Here is the message:

3 16 15 7 20 1 22 23 13 1 22 10 16 15 21 27 16 23 24 5 21 16 13 24 5 4 22 8 5 17 23 28 28 13 5 1 13 13 27 16 23 8 1 4 22 16 4 16 25 1 21 6 10 15 4 22 8 5 20 10 7 8 22 2 1 21 5 15 10 3 5 11 16 2

What does it say?

Comment: By the way, the solution is not just a simple numeric substitution cipher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plaintext:

> CONGRATULATIONSYOUVESOLVEDTHEPUZZLEALLYOUHADTODOWASFINDTHERIGHTBASENICEJOB

Method:

> Notice the digit 9 is missing from the message and assume base 9 is involved. Treat each group as a numeric value in base 9 and decipher using the "basic numeric substitution cipher" and "standard, regular alphabet" suggested by the puzzle.

Comment: Also note that [quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/) *does* accept numeric input and can be used to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Okay, I didn't even know what this tool was. Thanks! Maybe I made it too easy... nice in theory?